# requestSingleUpdate doesn't exist

Tags: android

I looked in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29
 and there is function requestSingleUpdate but in code in Eclipse I am getting error when I want to use requestSingleUpdate, like that function doesn't exists. Did anybody have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function was implemented in API level 9 (Android 2.3). Most likely your project targets a lower API level. You can raise the target level to 9 or greater. Or you can use [reflection](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) to test if this method is available on the phone your app gets executed and use it only in this case (+ have fallback code for older versions).

Answer (score 1):

It was introduced in API 9.  If you're using less than that, then it won't be available.